# how determine item position in ViewHolder when Swipe item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use RecyclerView in my project. And i want realize swipe functionality. I font this

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+swipeDir,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

But I do not understand, how determine item position and object in my List with this position?

Comment: shouldn't you override onMoved?

Answer (score 4):

Like that :

```
viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
```

Answer (score 1):

small snippet from my code to remove , onSwiped

```
int fromPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
studentList.remove(fromPos);
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(fromPos);
```